# Is this really just a sociological question?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

[What does it mean to "fetishise" someone else's race?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/94071/what-does-it-mean-to-fetishise-someone-elses-race?noredirect=1#)

My question was closed because someone felt that racial fetishisation was just a "social skills" question, nothing to do with ethics or philosophy, then.

It seems absurd to me. For starters, if fetishisation is always an awkward mistake, then no-one can do so intentionally. No-one, after meeting their black lover, boasts to their friends about having a black lover, for e.g. mutual feelings of condescension.

Is all non-violent racism just a "social skills" question? Again, it seems absurd to say there is no such thing as racist attitudes, just accidental racism.

Is there really no fact of the matter about what someone means when talking about race? etc..

Answer (score 2):

*Learning to communicate non-violently can be a subtle and long process, and a bit of humility is probably required here*. But here's a few tips on posing effective questions for the Q&A here.

In general framing open-ended problems is of course fine for the chat space but in the Q&A stack content should be *directed towards specific issues* you're encountering in *your study of philosophy*. So in this case I might suggest trying to emphasize as clearly as you can any interpretative questions you have w.r.t. some specific text. Because the post wanders around a bit, and isn't focused narrowly -- it risks reading like a rather unanswerably broad sociology of race quandary with *relatively little* to do with actual problems you're facing in your reading. Try to optimize for keeping the problem grounded in specific questions -- and especially consider emphasizing the ones you have *about the material you're studying*. Literature on the philosophical question of race is pretty vast and even asking for a general summary is a huge amount of work, and besides well-handled elsewhere (we are not an encyclopedia). Furthermore please consider posing multiple different questions as separate posts -- focus is key to keeping a question on-topic.

Comment: You are showing humility and a desire for "non-violence", but then IDT the close votes did. The question was fairly specific. I did not ask "what is racism" but "what is fetishisation wrt racism" which is close to "what is cultural appropriation" and there are articles on that very question that anyone can access

Comment: You make it sound like I'm hounding others, when it was not my comment/s that were deleted for rudeness (and rightly so). There are a lot of problems with this site, and a lack of specificity in how people respond to questions they don't like is one of them

Comment: Anyway, my apologies for my madness! Best of luck Jospeh.